# What is the the structure if combination claim?

Tags: structure, combination, combined

I have been trying to understand what is the structure of a combination claim.
The only information I found in internet is the following:

Combination claim. 
The preamble of this form of claim is considered to positively and clearly include all the elements or steps recited therein as a part of the claimed combination.

I appreciate if  someone could provide me with information "in easy to understand form"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to the "two part form" for claims? https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/f_iv_2_2.htm

Comment: I refer to US patents claims

Comment: Well the patent law in europe and the us is similar. I don't understand your question and google doesn't give anything useful for "combination claim", so you might want to give an example or specify.